# jQueryでHTMLElementに対してaddClass()を行いたい

Tags: jquery

jQueyのaddClass()を使いたいのですが、

```
$("#svg_textarea").addClass( "hoge" );
```

とやるとうまくいくものの、

```
$("#svg_textarea")[0].addClass( "hoge" );
```

とやるとうまくいきません。
HTMLElementに対してaddClass()を使うにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

というかそもそもjQueryを良くわかってないで使ってるからこういう所で躓く。
$("#svg_textarea")は配列のような物と理解しているんですが、その理解が違ってますか？

Comment: 配列のような物という理解でいいと思いますが、こういう場合内部実装を直接いじるようなやりかたは良くないです。`.get(0)`が同じような意味になります。それで、DOMエレメントを直接ゲットできます。`.addClass` がそれでうまくいかないのは、`.addClass`がjQueryのメソッドだからです。なので、jQueryオブジェクトに対して使う必要があります。DOMエレメントはそのメソッドを持っていないから使えないというワケです。

Comment: DOMエレメントに`.addClass` メソッドを適用するにはjQueryオブジェクトに変換しなければいけないですが、それは(元々jQueryオブジェクトだったのだから)本末転倒です。

Comment: それですね。私は完全にjQueryオブジェクトというものを理解していませんでした。
勉強するべきヒントを与えて下さって有難うございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eq()`を使います。

```
$('#svg_textarea').eq(0).addClass('hoge');
```

ちなみにですが、`id`指定は複数要素となる場合は使用しません(CSSの話になります)。
複数の要素に対して指定したい場合は`class`指定をする必要があります。

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // 一番目の要素にだけクラスを追加
    $('.svg_area').eq(0).addClass('hoge');
});
```

```css
.svg_area {
    width: 100px;
    background: #aaccff;
}
.hoge {
    background: #ddaaee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="svg_area">aaa</div>
<div class="svg_area">aaa</div>
<div class="svg_area">aaa</div>
```